# How to gather timezone of operating system from Oracle database in string format? (Migrate/convert date to ts with tz)

Tags: java, oracle, date, timezone, stored-functions

I want to update a database table which uses date type to `timestamp with timezone` type in such a way that the old dates get correct timezone information.

The plain cast is not good for me because if the time zone is for example UTC+2 hours (UTC+1 + 1 hour for daylightsaving) and I try to cast dates to `timestamp with timezone`, all the dates in the database table got the same +2 hour as timezone offset, regardless if it's a summer time or winter time date.

I already can write an SQL query which can determine about a date if it is in daylightsaving time or not, IF I know the current time zone in string format, e.g. 'Europe/Berlin'. The problem is that dbtimezone and sessiontimezone can be stored in other formats, too (+02:00, CET, etc). I cannot easily set the current sessiontimezone in a static way, because there are customers in several places on the globe with their own databases, but using a common update script.
Express method for timestamp can not help neither, because it cannot map the offset to named time zones.

I've seen a solution which uses java stored procedure to get the OS’s timezone instead of Oracles timezone. Unfortunately we use Oracle 12c, which contains an older JRE (I think it's 1.6 version). So, although Java 1.8 handles the timezones and daylight saving well (it uses updated tzmapping table), it does not work for me. I tryed it and if I run a test from Netbeans, then it gives me back the right time zone ID (in Europe/Berlin format), but even if it is accepted by Oracle SQL Developer, SQLPlus (which we use for running update scrips), it displays only +02:00.

I've tryied to use JodaTime (recompiled onto Java 1.6 in order to be accepted by SQL*Plus). The latest JodaTimes uses its own mapping table in theory. I read here on StackOverflow that if it cannot gather the time zone from `user.timezone` variable, then it turns to `java.util`, which is not good, as I mentioned. And if it does not succeed, then uses UTC. But it's not clear to me why it cannot get timezone from `user.timezone` systemm variable. Is it a permission problem maybe?
Or how could I possibly solve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: I can't read all that unformatted text, but if I understand your question correctly... - why not use the `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` data type, and be done with it?

Comment: In any case: the database server's time zone (set when the database was created or last altered) is available in `DBTIMEZONE`, and the client time zone is available in `SESSIONTIMEZONE`. Depending on your exact needs, you can use either one or the other as the second argument to `FROM_TZ()` (the first argument is your date, cast to a timestamp first).

Comment: You'll have a better chance of getting an answer and not having your question closed as unclear if you were to format your question text into something more readable. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.

Comment: Reading system property `user.timezone`in Java doesn’t require any permissions. Are you sure it has the correct value? You may want to play around with `System.getProperty` and `System.setProperty`. The latter will probably have effect only if you do it before touching any date and time classes.

Comment: PS You may look into [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) as an alternative to Joda-Time. It gives you the core functionality of Java 1.8 `java.time` and works on Java 1.6.

Answer (score 2):

If the data is already in an Oracle SQL table, and you must convert to a timestamp with time zone (for example, in a new column you created in the same table), you do not need to go explicitly to the OS, or to use Java or any other thing, other than the Oracle database itself.

It is not clear from your question if you must assume the "date" was meant to be in the server time zone (you mention "the database" which normally means the server) or the client time zone (you mention "session" which means the client). Either way:

```
update <your_table>
set <timestamp_with_time_zone_col> = 
            from_tz(cast<date_col> as timestamp, dbtimezone)
;
```

or use `sessiontimezone` as the second argument, if that's what you need.

This assumes that the database (and/or the session) time zone is set up properly in the db, respectively in the client. If it isn't / they aren't, that needs to be fixed first. Oracle is perfectly capable of handling daytime savings time, if the parameters are set correctly in the first place. (And if they aren't, it's not clear why you would try to get your operation to be "more correct" than the database supports in the first place.)

Example: in the WITH clause below, I simulate a table with a column `dt` in data type `date`. Then I convert that to be a `timestamp with time zone`, in my session's (client) time zone.

```
with
  my_table ( dt ) as ( 
    select to_date('2018-06-20 14:30:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual 
  )
select dt,
       from_tz(cast(dt as timestamp), sessiontimezone) as ts_with_tz
from   my_table
;

DT                  TS_WITH_TZ                                       
------------------- -------------------------------------------------
2018-06-20 14:30:00 2018-06-20 14:30:00.000000000 AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES
```

Answer (score 2):

The question in your title

> How to gather timezone of operating system from Oracle database in string format?

is easy to answer. Run this statement:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'tzr') FROM dual;
```

But I assume you have a different problem, however I don't fully understand it.

When you have a column of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` then the time zone information is available. Time zones like `+02:00` do not have any daylight savings, it is always 2 hour ahead UTC, no matter if summer or winter. Timezones like `Europe/Berlin` or `CET` apply Daylight Saving Times.

If you have a time for example `2018-06-22 10:00:00+02:00` then you simply don't know whether this means **Europe/Berlin with Daylight Saving Time on** or **Africa/Cairo** which is always +02:00 hours ahead UTC - you have no possibility to retrieve such information!

If you have data in column of `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) then you don't have any time zone information at all, thus you cannot convert such values to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` without further information.

Storing times in timezone of operating system is rather useless. Either store them in UTC or use data type `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`. Data in `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` are stored in `DBTIMEZONE` (which is recommended to be set as UTC but actually not relevant for you) and **always and only** shown in current user `SESSIONTIMEZONE`.

Comment: I think if I could get the current time zone of DB server in 'Continent/City' format I would be able to compute the correct tz information for dates which originally did not have this information.  I assume that all dates were saved in DB server's time(zone) and also that does not differ from tz of the client which created it (it is not a webapplication). Also UTC would be fine for me if only I could compute it, but it has the same problem: dates were not saved in UTC but in DB server's local time zone, so I cannot compute it without knowing the tz in that 'string' format (Continent/city).

Comment: You cannot ask for DB server time zone especially in 'Continent/City' format. If this is set as `+02:00` for example then that is what you get. If this is set as `Europe/Berlin` for example then that is what you get instead. Times are not stored in DB server's timezone (except for `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` data types)

Comment: That's why I want to get it from OS and not from Oracle. But so far nothing worked for me.

Comment: Obviously the time zone at OS is not defined as 'Continent/Region' - period, take it. You could also prove with `select EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_REGION FROM SYSTIMESTAMP) from dual;`

Comment: I don't agree. I can read user.timezone variable from Java. When tested in Netbeans it returns Europe/Berlin. When loaded into db as java function with loadjava tool Oracle SQL developer also says Europe/Berlin. But somehow in sqlplus it is +02:00. It seems very strange to me, because I thought it's OS variable and has nothing to do with DB system. Then how is it possible?

Comment: Most likely you mix DB server operating time zone with your Oracle user session time zone or time zone of you current Windows/Linux session. They can be all different.

Comment: Yes, I know. I would like to get the operating system's time from a (java?) stored procedure, but don't know how to do it exactly. Because as I mentioned the System.getProperty("user.timezone") way works only from O. SQL developer, but not from sqlplus.