# How to get the timezone ID from Oracle instead timezone offset

Tags: java, oracle, timezone

Is there a way to get the timezone id instead of the timezone offset from the oracle?
When I execute `SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIMEZONE FROM DUAL;` the returned result is `13-JAN-21 10.19.52.936031000 AM +05:30`.

When I retrieve this from Java using the `rs.getObject( "TIMEZONE ", ZonedDateTime.class )`, the ZonedDateTime object has both the `offset` and `zoneID` set to `+05:30`.

But what I expect to see is, `SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIMEZONE FROM DUAL;` should return `04-JAN-21 02.40.50.000000000 PM ASIA/COLOMBO` And the Java ZonedDateTime for the query should have the `offset` set to `+05:30` and the `zoneID` set to `Asia/Colombo`.

Is there a way to set up this in DB level or Java level? Current `DBTIMEZONE` is set to `+05:30`.

Comment: Please have a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271224/how-to-handle-day-light-saving-in-oracle-database/29272926#29272926

Comment: You need to set the Java time zone properly, e.g. with environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Duser.timezone=Asia/Colombo`

Answer (score 2):

if the data is already in an Oracle SQL table, and you must convert to a timestamp with time zone (for example, in a new column you created in the same table), you do not need to go explicitly to the OS, or to use Java or any other thing, other than the Oracle database itself.

It is not clear from your question if you must assume the "date" was meant to be in the server time zone (you mention "the database" which normally means the server) or the client time zone (you mention "session" which means the client). Either way:

```
update <your_table>
set <timestamp_with_time_zone_col> = 
            from_tz(cast<date_col> as timestamp, dbtimezone)
;
```

or use sessiontimezone as the second argument, if that's what you need.

This assumes that the database (and/or the session) time zone is set up properly in the db, respectively in the client. If it isn't / they aren't, that needs to be fixed first. Oracle is perfectly capable of handling daytime savings time, if the parameters are set correctly in the first place. (And if they aren't, it's not clear why you would try to get your operation to be "more correct" than the database supports in the first place.)

Example: in the WITH clause below, I simulate a table with a column dt in data type date. Then I convert that to be a timestamp with time zone, in my session's (client) time zone.

```
with
  my_table ( dt ) as ( 
    select to_date('2018-06-20 14:30:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual 
  )
select dt,
       from_tz(cast(dt as timestamp), sessiontimezone) as ts_with_tz
from   my_table
;

DT                  TS_WITH_TZ                                       
------------------- -------------------------------------------------
2018-06-20 14:30:00 2018-06-20 14:30:00.000000000 AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES
```

For Reference You can Check this Link [StackOverflow Ref. Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50978729/how-to-gather-timezone-of-operating-system-from-oracle-database-in-string-format)

Answer (score 1):

In a sense, you are out of luck. `SYSTIMESTAMP` simply returns what your operating system reports. The time zone is the time zone of the computer system hosting your database. It is **not** the database time zone (which may be something completely unrelated to where the DB actually resides) or the session time zone or anything like that. You will need to make the change in the db host OS itself, if you can.

If you know for sure that the system that hosts your database is in Sri Lanka, then you can get what you want indirectly like so:

```
select systimestamp AT TIME ZONE 'ASIA/COLOMBO' from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timezone at database level using `ALTER database` command as follows:

```
alter database set time_zone = '+05:30';
```

Please note that this will take effect after you restart your DB.

```
shutdown immediate
startup
```

Comment: As I stated in the question, the `SELECT DBTIMEZONE FROM DUAL;` returns `+05:30`. But I want this to be `Asia/Colombo`. Actually, I do not care what this query returns as long as the query `SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIMEZONE FROM DUAL;` retunrs `04-JAN-21 02.40.50.000000000 PM ASIA/COLOMBO` instead of `04-JAN-21 02.40.50.000000000 PM +05:30`

Comment: `systimestamp` reports the time zone of the operating system of the computer hosting the database. The database time zone has nothing to do with that. Indeed, I set my database time zone at +00:00, confirmed by `select dbtimezone from dual`; `systimestamp` has the time zone `-08:00`, which is the time zone of the Unix OS on my machine, on the West Coast of the U.S.

Comment: Changing the `DBTIMEZONE` has no effect on `SYSTIMESTAMP`, see other answers.

Comment: It is highly you will get what you want without creating a conversion function from offset to name. You may want to try Selecting from v$timezone_names. The problem is there are no less than 8 time zones with that offset. See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4fbb3daf14166557fad0a97c4f03fa95).

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle TZ_OFFSET() function returns the time zone offset from UTC of a valid time zone name or the SESSIONTIMEZONE or DBTIMEZONE function name.

```
TZ_OFFSET(value)
```

he TZ_OFFSET() function accepts one argument which can be a valid time zone name e.g., ‘Europe/London’, a function name of SESSIONTIMEZONE or DBTIMEZONE, or a time zone offset from UTC (which simply returns itself).

```
SELECT
  TZ_OFFSET( 'Europe/London' )
FROM
  DUAL;
```

The result would be +01:00

Comment: I want to get the ZoneID from ZoneOffset. This provides the other way around

Comment: Already two upvotes... for an answer that doesn't answer the question at all (in fact, it seems that the responder didn't understand the question to begin with). -1 from me.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get timezone.

```
SELECT systimestamp AS DBTime,
       systimestamp at time zone 'Europe/London',
       systimestamp at time zone 'America/Sao_Paulo'from dual;
```

---

```
SELECT
  TZ_OFFSET( DBTIMEZONE )
FROM
  DUAL;
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question? Two upvotes already... wow! -1 from me though.

Answer (score 0):

`SYSTIMESTAMP` is returned in the database operating system's time zone - so there is no way to change it within the database.

Don't mix the database operating system's time zone with `DBTIMEZONE`, they are different.

Also note, time zone `Asia/Colombo` is different to time zone `+05:30` although they have (currently) the same UTC Offset.

Time zone `Asia/Colombo` considers daylight saving times in case it would apply, and it also covers [changes](https://timezonedb.com/time-zones/Asia/Colombo). For example `Asia/Colombo` changed in 2006 from UTC+06:00 to UTC+05:30. Thus `TZ_OFFSET(TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 12:00:00 Asia/Colombo')` returns a different offset than `TZ_OFFSET(TIMESTAMP '2000-01-01 12:00:00 Asia/Colombo')`, for example.

Time zone `+05:30` is **always** 5:30h before UTC.

Your question is not really clear, what do you like to get?

Comment: What I expect is to have the `ZoneID` and `ZoneOffset` when I query `rs.getObject( "TIMEZONE ", ZonedDateTime.class` from Java. Say the column `TIMEZONE` has `SYSTIMESTAMP` as the value, then the `ZonedDateTime` object in Java has both the `ZoneID` and `ZoneOffset` set to `+05:30`. But I want `ZoneID` tobe `Asia/Colombo` and `ZoneOffset` to be `+05:30` in the `ZonedDateTime` object.

Comment: As written `SYSTIMESTAMP` is given in the database operating system's time zone, i.e. `+05:30`. If you insert this values into a table then that is the values which is inserted and displayed - period. If you like to **convert** time zone `+05:30` to `Asia/Colombo` then select `SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Colombo'`.